# Sine to square wave converter

Tags: sine

How I can make this sine to square wave converter accept higher frequency?

Because when I tested it, it only accepts 10KHZ max. I will need to input a higher level of frequency till 1000KHZ.

Would this mean that I need to swap the resistor values to lower values?

New to digital electronics. Would appreciate if someone could help. U1 is an Op Amp.

[image]

Comment: You forgot to state what U1 is.

Comment: Oh Oops. U1 is Op Amp.

Comment: There are thousands of opamps, fast ones and slow ones. But you use an opamp as a **comparator**, you might be better off using a comparator instead. Many comparators are designed for speed and faster than many opamps.

Comment: That circuit has no components to intentionally limit its operating frequency.  Any limit you are hitting is inherent to the opamp you are using.  You need to name that opamp.  Alternatively, you need to ask the question implicit in the information in the question.  The better question would be "How can I build a circuit to convert sine waves to square waves at up to 1MHz?"

Comment: @JRE Ok, so do you think it'll be a good idea to post the question you have suggested and delete this post?

Comment: What is the manufacturer's part number of op amp?

Comment: There are as yet no answers.  You could edit this, and ask that better question.  Leave the existing stuff as an example of what you think could work.  And, please finally add the part number of the opamp you were using.

Comment: @HandyHowie LM324, texas instrument

Comment: Ah.... eventually my question was answered. Use something much faster than an LM324 is my advice. Try a MAX999 comparator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a fast sine=>square wave converter, redo your circuit around a schmitt trigger.  A 74LS part would do.  Does the 4000 series have one?  I don't remember.  Oh yes...4093.

Comment: Hi @Robert Endl, thanks for the reply. Got it, am I able to use 74LS14, Hex schmitt trigger inverter?

Comment: I am limited to what my school can provide. My school does not have 4093.

Comment: Sort of.  74 logic output doesn't swing rail to rail very well.  4093 is a cleaner solution.  Or a 40HC93.